# SQL DateTimes From C# Linq to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a complex sql query that I have in a stored procedure and am calling from C#.

The procedure requires a date-time which I pass in as DateTime object from c#, the problem seems to occur with the format of the date. If I change the parameter to string and pass it in as 'yyyy-MM-dd' it works fine.

Is there anyway to use the datetime object?

Comment: "the problem" : what exception do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting the stored procedure parameter `SqlDbType` property to `SqlDbType.DateTime`?

```
SqlParameter p = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@date", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);

// set value
p.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

*(update)*

Also, I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425870/using-datetime-in-a-sqlparameter-for-stored-procedure-format-error).