# inserting datetimepicker value to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to insert a value from a datetimepicker value to a SQL Server table.

My table looks like this

```
Profile (Id, Name,..., DateofBirth(date)...)
```

I have tried this to convert datetime picker value to

```
string dt = dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss");

Insert into profile (id, DateofBirth)  
values(id,  CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT( varchar(11), dt, 101));
```

also use this

```
var date = new DateTime(dateTimePickerText);
```

also use this

```
DateTime date = DateBox.Value.Date;
string sDate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateInsert = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate);
```

but can't able to insert the date into the database. 2nd how can I retrieve back the date from database?

Comment: 1) what is the error message? 2) execute a sql SELECT.  That's probably not the kind of answer you are looking for, but I can't imagine what are you looking for.  Can you be more specific about your problem "how can I retrieve" ?  Are you using a SQLCommand object, or Linq, or dataset? Details, please.

Comment: Date is saved to the database using cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateofBirth",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=dateTimePicker but now i want to retreive it back and dolike this if(dateStored=datetime.now()) how can i do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must have to use `SqlParameter`.

```
 sql="Insert into profile (id, DateofBirth) values (@id,@DateofBirth)";
    using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,conn))
     {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id",SqlDbType.Int).Value=10;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateofBirth",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=dateTimePicker.Value;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
     }
```

Comment: Its work fine but during insertion of this commnd **cmd.Parameters.Add("@_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NameBox.Text;** it's prompts invalid object... how to insert it

Comment: Specify the size :  cmd.Parameters.Add("@_name", SqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value = NameBox.Text;

Comment: I got one more error now **cmd.Parameters.Add("@AccountId",SqlDbType.Int).Value = AccountInformation.AccountId;** where AccountInformation.AcountId contain integer value. but the error is **Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@AccountId' to data type int.**

Comment: @buddy - Double check the field type of AccountID in database. As per error description - the field AccountID and AccountInformation.AcountId must be int type.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd get into the habit of using parameters for all of your SQL queries. That way you avoid SQL injection attack vector and you can also specify the parameter type as datetime. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/425896/44540) for example.