# Pass a date from datepicker to sql server database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, datepicker

I have a datepicker textbox as below:

```
   <input type="text" id="txtdob" class="datepicker" style="width:154px"/>
```

I am not able to pass the value from this datepicker to my database table.Everything works fine so i am not going to post the entire code here.I am passing the value as below:

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtdob.value);
```

But it says could not find txtdob.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This has been previously asked:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904895/inserting-datetimepicker-value-to-sql-server-2008

Comment: Yes i have been through the above link before posting this question.Apparently, cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=txtdob.Value; doesnt work and still throws the same error. @TTeeple

Comment: This looks more like what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425870/using-datetime-in-a-sqlparameter-for-stored-procedure-format-error/425896#425896

Comment: The problem is in your .net code, not your SQL.   You should re-tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DOB",Data.SqlDbType.DateTime))
cmd.Parameters("@DOB").Value = txtdob.value;
```

Comment: No.it doesnt work.A lot of erros in the above statment.'New' does not exist in the current context.cmd.Parameters cannot be used as a method and still  txtdob cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.I just had to include runat=server to my textarea input.I knew this was a silly mistake but my question was right on point.