# converting datetime

Tags: c#

i want to convert Datetime. I don't know how to do this? It gives errors. nvarchar doesn't convert to datetime.

startDate format : "11.03.2012"

My table :
STARTDATE datetime
ENDDATE datetime

```
public static int Insert(string startDate, string endDate)
{

    Conn c = new Conn();
    SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[]{
    new SqlParameter("@STARTDATE", DateTime.ParseExact(startDate,"DD MM YYYY",null)),
    new SqlParameter("@ENDDATE",  DateTime.ParseExact(endDate,"DD MM YYYY",null)),        
    };

    return Convert.ToInt32(c.getObjectSP("sp_Insert", prms));
}
```

Comment: If you already know what the format is that your input comes in, why do you use a different mask when trying to parse it? Also, what is a Conn?

Comment: You can look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425870/using-datetime-in-a-sqlparameter-for-stored-procedure-format-error

Comment: When you say "It gives errors", you should post the details of these errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a date that is formatted like `"11.03.2012"`, you need to parse *with* the `.` in your format string.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(startDate,"dd.MM.yyyy",null)
```

Also note that `DD` and `YYYY` are **not** characters that are identified in the format string as parts of the datatime but are expected to be literals. See my example - `dd` for 2 characters for days and `yyyy` for 4 characters for year.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice article about it:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

```
// create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

Comment: A nice article and examples, but it doesn't really answer the question.