# How can I query a DataGridView using SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I need to query a `DataGridView` using SQL but don't show to `DataGridView`.

```
public chkTime()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

HRTaffDataContext db = new HRTaffDataContext();
SqlConnection Conn;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string appConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connDB"].ConnectionString;
string strDate;

private void chkTime_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connStr();
    return;
}

public void connStr()
{
    Conn = new SqlConnection();
    if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        Conn.Close();
    }
    Conn.ConnectionString = appConn;
    Conn.Open();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(appConn);

    string sql = "SELECT [filesTA].EmpNo,[Employee].[First Name],[filesTA].ChkDate,[filesTA].ChkIn,[filesTA].ChkOut,[CompanyData].ShortName"
    + " From [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA] inner join [WebSP].[dbo].[Employee] on [Employee].EmployeeNo=[filesTA].EmpNo INNER JOIN [WebSP].[dbo].[CompanyData] On [CompanyData].Company = [Employee].Company"
    + " WHERE [filesTA].ErrorCode = 0"; // It's work
    + " WHERE [filesTA].ErrorCode = 0 and [filesTA].ChkDate ='" + dateTimePicker.Text.ToString() + "'";

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    Conn.Close();

    dgvShow.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

- `"WHERE [filesTA].ErrorCode = 0"` works fine.
- `"WHERE [filesTA].ErrorCode = 0 and [filesTA].ChkDate ='" + dateTimePicker.Text.ToString() + "'"` does not work.

I need to set where `DateTime`.

Comment: That means your [filesTA].ChkDate doesn't match the date you selected.

Comment: FYI, why don't you use the `SQLParameter`? Easy to use and prevent any SQL injection. [Here you can see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/425896/1498857) a little example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `dateTimePicker.Value.ToString()` instead of `dateTimePicker.Text.ToString()`

A simple example of using this can be `dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: thanks so much. i try dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 

it's workd. :D

Answer (score 1):

$dateTimePicker.Text returns a string for human reading and your server maybe don't like it.

Try something like:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT [filesTA].EmpNo,[Employee].[First Name],[filesTA].ChkDate,[filesTA].ChkIn,[filesTA].ChkOut,[CompanyData].ShortName"
            + " From [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA] inner join [WebSP].[dbo].[Employee] on [Employee].EmployeeNo=[filesTA].EmpNo INNER JOIN [WebSP].[dbo].[CompanyData] On [CompanyData].Company = [Employee].Company"
            + " WHERE [filesTA].ErrorCode = 0 and [filesTA].ChkDate ='{0}-{1}-{2}'",
                dateTimePicker.Value.Year,
                dateTimePicker.Value.Month,
                dateTimePicker.Value.Day);
```

Comment: thank so much! it's work. :D

='{0}-{1}-{2}'" << does it's mean??